# Responsive Nav Menu Fit

Tags: css

I'm making my first responsive website and have a small problem with the nav menu.

It snaps to the virtual grid for most size, but as you reduce the window size horizontally it gets to a point where it loses the position. I have a min-width set to 350px for the rest of the window and want it to snap to the virtual lines that the rest of the site constrain to.
Currently the "right: 12.5%" causes it to follow the border.

The website can be found here: www.ultimate-punch.com

```
    /*MEDIA QUERY*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 960px) {
    #main_menuicon {
        display:inline-block;
    }

    nav ul, nav:active ul { 
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background: #000;
        border: 5px solid #444;
        top: 30px;
        width: 150px;
        right: 12.5%;
        margin: auto;
        height: 200px;
        line-height: 1;
    }

    nav li {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 18px;
        word-wrap: normal;
    }

    nav:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }

    #main_nav li {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: not really sure what is the question here..

Comment: What can be done to fix it?

Comment: Maybe be only me, but what needs to be fixed?

Comment: "It snaps to the virtual grid for most size, but as you reduce the window size horizontally it gets to a point where it loses the position"

When then window becomes a certain reduced width, the hover over nav menu no longer fits to the side of the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, delete  `position: absolute` for your `nav ul`.

Then, add this to `#main_menuicon` (on the regular stylesheet, not the media query):

```
    #main_menuicon {
      height: 25px;
      margin-top: 14px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Removing the position: absolute did the trick and just redefined margins where appropriate